# RPA/Selenium to Perform TIN Matching

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, rpa, winappdriver

I am trying to automate a process where I am verifying a TIN (tax id number) on the IRS website. I thought it would be easy but when I run my test - the IRS website gives me a “technical error” code 4405. If I do it manually it’s no issue.  I tried to back door it using executejavascript to no avail and tried using findelement.Click to emulate a human.

Since everyone is afraid of the IRS (myself included)- I started to think maybe they are detecting an automated browser instance and maybe I breaking an agreement I click through but didn’t see any.  So assuming I am compliant and maybe overthinking it, how does one get through this ? It’s happened before using Oracle EBS but I just deferred in that case.

Are web apps detecting Selenium and preventing automation ?  I understand why in some cases , but how does one circumnavigate for legit cases such as automating testing. Do I have to automate through win app driver?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe the IRS is using/checking for automation programs such as Selenium (see [Can a website detect when you are using Selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver))